# Easiest multiple file upload with minimal "plugins"

Tags: php, javascript, html, file-upload

I want to do a multiple file upload (you know, the kind that says "choose your image(s)" and actually lets you select more than one from the fileup dialogue),

What's the EASIEST way to do this (I know someone's going to say jQuery), using raw PHP as the backend?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do it with "minimal" plugins? The notions of "minimal plugins" and "easy" seem to be at odds with each other - the plugins (SWFUpload, Uploadify, etc) *make* it easy - they abstract away all the complicatedness.

Comment: I meant easy from the perspective of not having to find and install stuff

Comment: I'm fairly sure the only cross browser technique involves both javascript and flash, so there's always going to be a need to "install stuff". If you're alright with supporting only shiny/new/not_IE browsers, @Andris' answer looks good. Otherwise, you're stuck with something like Uploadify.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be using HTML5 built in multiple file uploader

```
<input type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple="true"/>
```

But this currently works only with the newest Safari, Chrome and Firefox. For any other browsers you need to fall back to the good old Flash component like [SWFUpload](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/index.htm) or any other.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this without browser-side plug-in (such as Flash - even javascript won't be enough, you need filesystem access) if you want it universally compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I have used **[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/)** before, and I can say it was *very easy* to use. Look at the last demo on that page.

It uses jQuery, and even comes with a small sample PHP script.